# Surface gravity inside a star

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon

In general relativity, there is a definition of the [surface gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_gravity) that is associated with the Killing vectors, is there a similar definition for the interior of stars/compact objects?

I would expect that if I measure the surface gravity inside and near the surface of the star and outside it should be the same.

Comment: In §5.2.4 of Poisson's *A Relativist's Toolkit* there's a discussion of how in a spherically symmetric metric, the quantity $-\frac{1}{2} \partial g_{tt}/\partial r$ can be interpreted as the "force at infinity" required to keep an object stationary at any radius.  This quantity is equal to the surface gravity when evaluated at the horizon.  But I'm not sure how this changes for axisymmetric spacetimes, or whether there's a nice coordinate-independent characterization of this quantity that applies when the KVF is non-null.